# Enforce relative links to defs in SVG

Tags: svg, d3.js

I'm trying to draw multiple SVGs on a single page and the ids in the defs section of each SVG are clashing. I'd like each one to refer only the mask in their own defs. Currently they all use the mask that has a matching id on the first svg on the page. No svg knows about the others so they would have to rely on a random number generator to pick ids that (hopefully) are different.

Is that possible or do they need unique ids if the SVGs are loaded into the same webpage. They are created on the fly by d3.

```
<svg>
    <defs>
        <mask id="temperatureMask">
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#ffffff">
        </mask>
    </defs>
    <rect mask="#temperaureMask">…etc
</svg>


<svg>
    <defs>
        <mask id="temperatureMask">
            <rect width="100%" height="50%" fill="#dddddd">
        </mask>
    </defs>
    <rect mask="#temperaureMask">…etc
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ids on a page must be unique.  That includes any inline SVGs.  You will need to alter your d3 script like you suggest to add a unique number etc to the ids.